# Setting timezone = "Asia/Kolkata" in @jsonformat and storing it in java.sql.timestamp converts 12 pm to 1 pm timesatmp to 00 am in spring hibernate

Tags: spring-data-jpa, timezone, timestamp-with-timezone, sql-timestamp

I am using

```
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss", timezone = "Asia/Kolkata")
private Timestamp startDateTime;
```

to store timestamp comes in json as a string.
But the problem is it converts time between 12 pm to 1 pm into 00 am.
E.g. `2021-10-25 12:30:00` gets converted to `2021-10-25 00:30:00`.
Any help will be appreciated.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The root cause of the problem is that you have used `h` instead of `H`. Note that `h` is used for 12-hour time format (i.e. time with AM/PM marker) while `H` is used for 24-hour time format. So, the solution to your problem is to change the format to `dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss`.

In case, you want the AM/PM marker in the time, change the format to `dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss a`.

Comment: That was the exact solution that helped me.
Thanks a ton.